# Equivalence of non-homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let G be an open set in $R^n$, $f:G\to R^n$ a continuous injection. I need to show that $f:G \to f(G)$ is not a homeomorphism if and only if there exists a sequence $Xn$ that converges to some point on the boundary of G or to $\infty$ so that $b=limit_{n\to\infty}f(Xn)$ exists and belongs to $f(G)$.

I proved the second direction, but I'm stuck with the first direction. I know that if $f$ is not a homeomorphism then $f^{-1}$ is not continuous but I don't know how to proceed. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You have been around for more than a year. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [mathjax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to typeset your questions? Besides, what is the second direction”?

Comment: What i need is "Assuming f is not a homeomorphism... Prove the other condition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theorem (invariance of domain) says that if $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f: G \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective, then in fact $f$ **is** a homeomorphism between $G$ and $f[G]$ and $f[G]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So the condition that such an $f$ exists which is not a homeomorphism does not occur. From a false stetement you can prove anything you like (ex falso quodlibet)..

Comment: Ok I will try to work with that. Thank you!